# TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined on unit testing angular app

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am running the unit test for an angular app. I expect ngOnInit to be called, but the test fails as  TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined.

This is Component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.topToolBarService.change.subscribe(customer => {
      this.filter.customerid = customer;
      this.customerid = customer;
      this.getData();

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your service initialized?

Have you tried

```
this.topToolBarService.change().subscribe(...
```

best regards

Comment: @Output() change: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

Comment: This is the only line in the service that refers to change

Comment: Ok;
First: If you don't have such a line "this.change.emit(true)" - your EventEmitter is really useless;
Second: The braces after "change" are the difference between your and my code